# Как с помощью javascript считать строку внутри тега 'span'?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

```
<span class="letter">1987</span>
```

как присвоить переменной число 1987?

Comment: Очень просто..... `var chislo = document.querySelector('span').innerHTML`

Comment: а если тег span не один?

Comment: Все зависит от желаемого конечного результата....

Answer (score 0):

> Как с помощью javascript считать **строку** внутри тега 'span'?

Вот так можно читать:

```js
var sps = document.querySelectorAll('.letter')
var res = [];
// Пройдем по массиву
sps.forEach(function (s) { 
  res.push(s.innerText) // Собираем текст в массив
})
console.log(res);
```

```html
<div class="">
  <span class="letter">1987</span>
  <span class="letter">1988</span>
  <span class="letter">1989</span>
  <span class="letter">1990</span>
</div>
```

---

- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) - Возвращает список элементов в пределах документа (поиск осуществляется в пределах указанного элемента) которые соответствуют указанной группе селекторов.